# Gallery using Paperclip in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a Vendor model:

```
 has_many :galleries
has_many :photos, :through=>:galleries
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :galleries
```

Gallery model:

```
has_many :photos
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
```

Photo model:

```
    belongs_to :gallery
belongs_to :vendor
```

In Vendor controller:

```
def new
@vendor=Vendor.new(vendor_params)
@vendor.galleries.build.photos.build
end

def vendor_params
params.require(:vendor).permit(galleries_attributes:[photos_attributes:[:photo=>[]]])
end
```

In vendor/new.html.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :galleries do |g| %>
<%= g.fields_for :photos do |p| %>
<%= render 'photo_fields', :f=> p %>
<%= link_to_add_association 'Add Photos',f,:photos %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

I am getting an error the following error:

```
Started POST "/vendors" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-09 23:31:17 +0530
Processing by VendorsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1fUkNShGMhZoT1EyYRB0v08XtVpY72C5yBXFLIFz5o0=", "vendor"=>{"galleries_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"gallery_name"=>"brochure", "photos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f4630246328 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150109-5672-1w996al>, @original_filename="Screenshot", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"vendor[galleries_attributes][0][photos_attributes][0][photo]\"; filename=\"Screenshot\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}}}}}, "commit"=>"Continue"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Photo(#69969748596420) expected, got Array(#17246380)):
  app/controllers/vendors_controller.rb:96:in `create'
```

Comment: You mean you see a log entry stating that some parameter is not allowed? If yes, could you please post the error from your log together with the parameters (the part after "Started POST .. Processing by <controllername> as <format>"?

Comment: This is the error
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Photo(#50673840) expected, got Array(#17246380)):

Comment: Could you add the full error, including the stack trace to your question please?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the stack trace. 

I am uploading 2 images currently.

Comment: It would also be handy to be able to see the `create` action where the error occurs, and the full strack trace of the error.